# How to pass parameters to Sublime Text Macro?

Tags: macros, sublimetext2

I'ld like to pass a parameter to a Sublime Text 2 Macro.

For example I'ld like to pass an ID_PARAMETER to macro that when run would ask for the ID_PARAMETER and output an URL like:

```
http://site.example.com/?id=ID_PARAMETER
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there something keeping you from using a regular [snippet](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) in this case?